# Special Characters in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, configuration

My password contains special characters like '&' and VS giving error on this like Password=abcdef!@hh&held

How can I use special characters in my web.config file?

Comment: In fairness, if a person fell out of bed tomorrow and decided to do .NET programming, the web.config/app.config would be their first exposure to XML. Nothing wrong with that. It's issues like this that force people to dabble in XML in the first place.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since the web.config file is an XML file, the values need to be XML encoded:

```
Password=abcdef!@hh&amp;held
```

Note how `&` is replaced by `&amp;`

Comment: List of characters that need to be encoded in XML:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Comment: can a password containing equal to (=) sign is allowed in web.config? I don't see it in special character list.

Answer (score 8):

The web.config is like any other XML file, so certain characters need to be encoded.

For example, `&` should be written as `&amp;`.